# Bind Text to size

Tags: c#, winforms, binding

How can i bind a Text property from a textBox to a Width of a panel?

I tried:

```
   panel1.DataBindings.Add("Text", textBox3, "Size.Width");
```

but it raises exception

```
Object does not match target type.
```

**EDIT**: I want to change the width of panel, as text in textbox is changed.

Comment: You would need to implement a [`TypeConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.aspx) the converts from `string` to `int` and use this converter in the binding.

Comment: please expand your questions details...

Comment: @kilotaras: sorry, my comment doesn't apply. I thought you were using WPF.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want a text property to display the pixel width of a panel as it changes at runtime?

Comment: @ChrisBD: The other way around.

Comment: @Chris No. Scenario. I change text to 10 - width changes to 10. I change text to 15 - width changes to 15. No error/type checking, i.e. its always integer in textbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
void MakeBind()
{
     Binding bind = new Binding("Width", textBox3, "Text");
     bind.Format += new ConvertEventHandler(bind_Format);
     panel1.DataBindings.Add(bind);
}
void bind_Format(object sender, ConvertEventArgs e)
{
     int i = 0;
     int.TryParse((string)e.Value, out i);
     e.Value = i;
}
```

You also should know, that you can't directly change Size.Width, because of Size is a property, which returns value type, which you can't change this way. Only to set new Size with new Width.

Comment: Stupid me. Works as a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

try

`panel1.DataBindings.Add("Text", int.TryParse(textBox3.text), "Size.Width");`

Comment: -1: Sorry to say that, but you have no idea how data bindings work.